# Passing arguments via npm scripts

Tags: npm, npm-scripts, npm-run

I've read a bunch of answers suggesting to do something like

```
npm run dev -- --nodebug:true
```

but what I then see executed is

```
webpack-dev-server --hot --colors --port 3000 "--nodebug:true"
```

I do not want these quotes as then the next part of the passing of arguments does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried `npm run dev --nodebug true` ?

Comment: nothing gets passed onto the next command. And `npm run dev -- --nodebug true` --> `webpack-dev-server --hot --colors --port 3000 "--nodebug" "true"`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. You can run:

```
npm run dev nodebug=true
```

On your main js file you can use the following code to retrieve the parameters.

```
process.argv.forEach((val, index) => {
  console.log(`${index}: ${val}`)
})
```

And it will print something like this in your console:

> 0: /usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v9.11.2/bin/node
>
> 1: /var/www/html/project/backend/bin/www
>
> 2: nodebug=true